# Did the rep level for edit and close-votes just get changed?

Tags: discussion

Did the rep level for edit and close-votes just get changed?    Last month I was able to participate in close-voting and edits, but not I have lost those privileges.

I don't see any meta question discussing this -- so were there an announcement of this change? and how is it decided?

**Update**

As you can see from this [image: review-list] my blue picture is in the review list for "suggested edit", "close votes" etc -- which I was able to review a month ago, however it now claims that I need at least 1k rep to do these reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a recent change to the privileges code base - it was completely overhauled and inadvertently, some of the specific overrides for Ask Patents did not get properly migrated.

These have now been fixed - apologies for the disruption.

Comment: Meta privs have not been fixed. Please fix.

Comment: Don't know where you are getting that from. The original overrides have been re-implemented identically. If you think there is a bug/issue, please be more descriptive than "have not been fixed".

Comment: I already [reported](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/229/why-dont-i-have-ability-to-edit-posts-on-meta-having-editing-priveleges) it.

Comment: Meta privileges there are like privileges on any beta site (500 to close, 1k to edit), but they should be special as on the [main] (250 to close, 250 to edit). Please fix it.

Comment: @nicael - oversight, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks! So tag [this question](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/229/why-dont-i-have-ability-to-edit-posts-on-meta-having-editing-priveleges) with [status-completed] please :)